# Adding MySQL connector java to modular Javafx project when packaging with maven

Tags: mysql, maven, intellij-idea, javafx, module

I make a modular Javafx project with maven and Intellij 2021 .1.3 . And i want to use MySQL to it. I added the dependencies to pom.xml like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>AccountZeyny</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>AccountZeyny</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <javafx.version>15</javafx.version>
        <javafx.maven.plugin.version>0.0.6</javafx.maven.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <organization>
        <!-- Used as the 'Vendor' for JNLP generation -->
        <name>ORGZ</name>
    </organization>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
            <version>17-ea+9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.25</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>15</source>
                    <target>15</target>
                    <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compress>2</compress>
                    <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                    <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                    <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                    <launcher>AccountZeyny</launcher>
                    <jlinkImageName>AccountZeyny</jlinkImageName>
                    <jlinkZipName>AccountZeyny</jlinkZipName>
                   <mainClass>AccountZeyny/org.openjfx.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

then add the dependency in the module-info.java:

```
module AccountZeyny {
requires javafx.fxml;
requires javafx.controls;
requires java.sql;
requires javafx.swing;
requires mysql.connector.java;
opens org.openjfx to javafx.fxml;
exports org.openjfx;
exports org.openjfx.controllers to javafx.fxml;
opens org.openjfx.controllers to javafx.fxml;
exports org.openjfx.controllers.list to javafx.fxml;
opens org.openjfx.controllers.list to javafx.fxml;
exports org.openjfx.controllers.dataScreenControllers to  javafx.fxml;
opens org.openjfx.controllers.dataScreenControllers to javafx.fxml;
exports org.openjfx.controllers.dialogControllers to javafx.fxml;
opens org.openjfx.controllers.dialogControllers to javafx.fxml;
exports org.openjfx.settergetters to javafx.base;
opens org.openjfx.settergetters to javafx.base;}
```

when running it with Plugins->javafx->javafx:run it works fine. but when i try to package the project i get the warning:

```
* Required filename-based automodules detected: [mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar]. Please don't publish this project to a public artifact repository! *
```

and when running i get error:

```
no main manifest attribute, in D:\Account-Zeyny\target\AccountZeyny-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Any help??

Comment: That's because MySQL driver doesn't have a module declaration (module-info.java)

Comment: The main manifest, is due to manifest.mf is not containing the main attribute, which should point to the class with the main method.

Comment: i added the manifest attribute in pom.xml and it run. but i have new error now:
No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/".......something".
i don't know what is MySQL Driver declaration in module-info.java. isn't it 
"requires mysql.connector.java;"?